# jsf PrimeFaces how to close modal form

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I created a modal form. while the submit button works fine:

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" value="save" action="#{editErReferencesFormWebBean.submit}" />
```

I don't know how to create a cancel button that just closes the dialog. I don't want to call the server for it.
Is there a simple way to just close the dialog (and discard all inputs)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading Primefaces documentation:

```
    <p:dialog widgetVar="modal" modal="true" closable="false">
     <!-- Modal content -->
     <h:form id="form">
        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="PF('modal').hide();$('#form').trigger('reset');" type="button" />
      </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

Also, you could set `closable` attribute to `true` for displaying `X` icon which closes the dialog.

Comment: OP don't want to call the server.

Comment: closable is a valid option. is there a way to get the same functionality for a button?

Comment: Putting `type="button"`, the button doesn't call the server. `PF('modal').hide();` closes the modal and `$('#form').trigger('reset');` cleans the form changes.

Comment: it is working i edited your answer a bit to clarify "#form"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
        <p:commandButton value="Modal" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg').show();" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" id="myDialog" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" height="100">

        <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />
        <p:inputText/>

        <button id="myButton" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" onclick="$('#form\\:myDialog').hide(); $('#form\\:myDialog_modal').remove();$('#form').trigger('reset');">
            <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">
                My Button
            </span>
        </button>

    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Regards.

Comment: i tried this but this isn't working. probably i did something wrong by substituting "myDialog"? could you please show a complete example (i am totally new to jsf/primefaces)

Comment: Update my answer with a complete example, I hope it helps you.